# How do i fix position of object in object mode and edit mode?

Tags: rigging, vertices

I'm trying to make clothes of a character to move with rest of the body but for some reason sleeves don't want to cooperate.
The way I do it is I select sleeves then body. Next I go to Object->Link/Transfer data->Transfer Mesh Data->Vertex Groups->set Source Layers to All Layers. After all this i add armature modifier to those sleeves and add to object my armature.
When I'm done with this, sleeves have different position in object mode and in edit mode. This whole process seems to work on some other piece of clothing but this one and I tried redoing this process but failed every time.
Is there a way to fix this issue?[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your object (remove the head if you don't want to fully share it): https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 layers of bones, for the moment the layer *Deform* is invisible:

[image]

If you make it visible, you'll see that these bones are not aligned with the ones that they are supposed to copy with a *Copy Transform* constraint (and that are in the *Driver* layer). As soon as you'll switch to *Pose* mode they will align, and they will move your mesh:

[image]

The solution can be to align these *Deform* bones with the *Driver* bones.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working!